# Typescript React - map array as component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have the following sub component I created and I want to use it as

```
<LangsLinks/>
```

inside main component **in the same file**. typescript throwing errors.

```
  const LangsLinks: (): JSX.Element[]  => {
    return appLinks.map((link) => {
      return (
        <Link key={link.text} href={link.relativeLink}>
          {link.text}
        </Link>
      )
    })
  }

error : 'LangsLinks' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

when I try to use Element[] I'm getting another error missing ReactElement<any, any>
so I try to add it and so on. the app is work but I want to understand why is that happening. I dont want to use 'any'

the main component which I using the langLinks:

```
  return (
    <>
      <OneZeroSkipToMainContent
        text={'skipToMainContent'}
        dir={dir}
        className={'h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-pink-500'}
      />
      <header className=" z-50 justify-center   overflow-hidden  bg-gradient-to-br   ">
        <div className="flex mt-8  fixed z-50 right-2/4 p-4 translate-x-2/4  gap-x-2 mx-auto bg-light rounded-lg sm:w-150 lg:w-160 mobile:w-screen justify-between">
          <Logo />
          <ul className="flex flex-row gap-x-2   self-stretch">
            <div className="lg:flex flex-row gap-x-6  w-4/4  items-center hidden  md:visible  ">
              <LangsLinks />
            </div>
          </ul>
          <ul className="flex flex-row gap-x-2 items-center  mx-r-auto  w-1/3 justify-end mobile:hidden  sm:block md:flex">
            {langs.map((lang, i) => {
              return (
                <li key={lang}>
                  <ChangeLangButton
                    src={`/icons/flags/${i + 1}.png`}
                    lang={lang}
                  ></ChangeLangButton>
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
          <div className="sm:block md:hidden pl-10 cursor-pointer  relative  ">
            <Image src="/header/mobile-menu.svg" alt="menu" layout="fill" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: How are you using LangsLinks?

Comment: I will add the extra code

Comment: Thats more like it but still error :
'Links' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2786)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why are you trying to set a type to your component return. Just build it like a normal functional component, I'll rewrite it a bit:

```js
const LangsLinks = () => {
    return (
       <>
          {appLinks.map((link) => (
              <Link key={link.text} href={link.relativeLink}>
                {link.text}
              </Link>
            )
          )}
       </>
      )
  }
```

Just keep it simple, it does not work for you this way?

EDIT: Even more simple:

```js
const LangsLinks = () => (
           <>
              {appLinks.map((link) => (
                  <Link key={link.text} href={link.relativeLink}>
                    {link.text}
                  </Link>
                )
              )}
           </>
          )
```

Comment: Typescript throwing errors with or without typs. and its good practice to understand how to use typescript

Comment: @YanivCode JSX.Element[] is not valid type here; you can use ReactNode instead. yet in all cases, you need to wrap array in a fragment, and as mentioned above type is not required if function has no chains return type can be infered from usage.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot return multiple root nodes from a component. you will need to wrap it with <> or React.Fragment;

example:

```
  const LangsLinks = () => {
    return <React.Fragment> 
      {appLinks.map((link) => {
        return (
          <Link key={link.text} href={link.relativeLink}>
            {link.text}
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  }
```

Comment: Not working Sadly

Comment: may be your setup does not allow <> . use     <React.Fragment>
instead @YanivCode